# How to do clickable ListView after HTML parsing (get "href=")

Tags: android, html, listview

I do html parsing like this
[Android HTML Parser Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867746/android-html-parser-example)

Now I have a listView with a searchresult from site.
How do I get the "href=" of this item and then go to this site?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below code u can get the `href` of the element if u pass the element as the argument. Then u can proceed by going to the site.

```
 public static String getTagValueWithMultiItem(Element eElement){
                 String returnVal = "" ;
                 Node eNode ;
                 int NumOFItem = eElement.getElementsByTagName("link").getLength();
                 for (int y = 0; y < NumOFItem; y++) {
                 eNode = eElement.getElementsByTagName("link").item(y);
                 NamedNodeMap attributes = eNode.getAttributes();
                  for (int g = 0; g < attributes.getLength(); g++) {
                      Attr attribute = (Attr)attributes.item(g);
                                 if(attribute.getNodeName().equals("rel")&&attribute.getNodeValue().equals("alternate"))
                                    {
                                      try { 
                                            returnVal =eNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("href").getNodeValue();
                                           }  
                                         catch (Exception e) {
                                            returnVal = e.toString();
                                         }
                                     } 
                                  }
                 }
                return returnVal;    
             }
```