# Reading HTML source from android app

Tags: android, html, http, httpclient, http-get

I'm trying to get the HTML source in a string from a web site that the user enters, the code I have so far looks like this:

```
public String getURLContent(String url)
{
    try 
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
        return page;
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Every time I try to run this I hit the second catch (IOException), which according to the documentation means the server failed to give a valid response... I am testing this with sites like "http:\www.google.com\", so they should definitely be responding

Comment: Have you added the required permissions such as android.permission.INTERNET   ?

Comment: I only have this one permission:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Are there others?

Comment: If that is actually your url then it is incorrect. You'd prolly need two slashes before the 'www'

Comment: there is nothing wrong in the code! just make sure your url is correct.. "http://(domain)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok. Make sure you paste full website path : `http://www. [page] . [domain]` eg.: `http://www.google.com`
And add this PERMISSION to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

just before (if it is new project):

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Full example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, my manifest looks exactly like this, I am sure I'm using the correct addresses (I've tried many), still not working correctly, still gets caught as an IOException when I call httpClient.execute()... I'm pulling my hair out now that you guys have told me the code looks right!

Comment: try use debugger and check variables' values step by step

Comment: and try put website address into `new HttpGet(...` at least you will be sure that address website is not the problem

Comment: I figured it out, I think... I had a breakpoint set in that catch block and I was always hitting it. I assumed this meant that the error was actually being caught, but when I checked the return value the HTML source was in the string that was returned, so I am assuming this was an error in the debugger, because I shouldn't have hit that breakpoint, or if I actually did hit that breakpoint the string returned from the function should have been empty, and it was not. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to do some custom parsing with the whole string, I would advise you to use an HTML parser lib. I use HTML cleaner, showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867746/android-html-parser-example).

That makes all the horse work for you.

Comment: I edited the answer because it was missing the link. Sorry, my bad. ;)