# Parsing HTML in Android

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, html-parsing

I have html code that looks like

```
<td align="right"><select name="Hour">
<option >00</option>
<option >01</option>
<option >02</option>
<option >03</option>
<option >04</option>
<option >05</option>
<option >06</option>
<option selected>07</option>
<option >08</option>
<option >09</option>
<option >10</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;:
</td>
```

HTML I parsing contain few blocks of code like this with only difference in `<select name="Hour">` tag. So as input I have only name of tag. As output I need to get value of **selected** option . Can someone give me a hint or help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private String getDateComponentFromHTML(String componentName, String html) {
    String dateComponent = null;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<select name=\"" + componentName + "\".*?<.*?selected.*?\\(d{2})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    if (m.find()) {
        dateComponent = m.toMatchResult().group(1);
    }
    return dateComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options at least. Best is to look at [Android HTML Parser Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867746/android-html-parser-example)

If not any of those libs, maybe try parsing it as XML?