# Can’t Scrape the image url from a website

Tags: php, android, html, parsing

I'm trying to **scrape** the image url from [Uefa website](http://www.uefa.com/rssfeed/news/rss.xml) using Jsoup but I encounter an error. This is the code that I'm using it to retrive the images url.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Utility.url).get();
Elements img = doc.select("img");
```

I used Breakpoints to see wich line doesn't work and I found that the doc variables is working correctly getting all the page scraped but when I debug the next line I get null and an Array with 0 Objects. I already looked on stackoverflow but I couldn't find a solution for my problem so I tried `Elements img = doc.title();` and worked perfectly. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<head></head>
<body onload="SubscribeHandler.writeContent();" onunload="SubscribeHandler.uninit();">
    <div id="feedHeaderContainer"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript"></script>
    <div id="feedBody">
        <div id="feedTitle"></div>
        <div id="feedContent">
            <div class="entry">
                <h3></h3>
                <div class="feedEntryContent" base="http://www.uefa.com/rssfeed/news/rss.xml"></div>
                <div class="enclosures">

                    Media files

                    <div class="enclosure">
                        <img class="type-icon" src="moz-icon://.txt?size=16"></img>
                        <a href="http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Photo/competitions/Comp_Matches/01/81/52/90/1815290_s5.jpg"></a>

                         (2.0 KB)

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="entry"></div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="entry"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of places where you are going wrong:
1. You want to parse a XML RSS feed. For parsing XML RSS feed you need to use the 'xmlParser' of JSoup.

1. You want to get the image URLs. The image URLs are in the 'enclosure' tag with attribute 'url'. They is no 'img' tag in the RSS feed. So, you need to read the 'enclosure' tag and not the 'img' tag.

I am attaching the code below to pull the image URLs. This code has been tested by me. Let me know in case of any issues.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://www.uefa.com/rssfeed/news/rss.xml";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).ignoreContentType(true).get();
        for (Element x : doc.getElementsByTag("enclosure")) {
            System.out.println(x.attr("url"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used SAX and I parsed the enclosure tag but anyway you're answer is the right one. I figured out finally

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use HTML parser to get value from html data. here is nice [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868079/942224). go through it

Comment: I implement the code in my application and I get the same result I was getting it with Jsoup.